# why this program gives a "segmentation fault" when run on my linux?

Tags: c, linux, loops, if-statement

Write a program for a match stick game being played between the computer and a user.Your program should ensure that the computer should ensure that the computer always wins.Rules for the game are as follows:
-There are 21 matchsticks.
-The computer asks the player to pick 1,2,3 or 4 matchsticks.
-After the person picks,the computer does its picking.
-Whoever is forced to pick up the last matchstick loses the game.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n,rem;
    printf("Initially 21 mathces\n");

    rem=21;
    for(;1;)
    {   
    if(rem==1){
                printf("Com wins\n");
                break;
}
else if(rem==0){
                printf("Player wins\n");
                break;
                }
else{
        printf("Player's turn.Enter number:");
        scanf("%d",n);
        rem=rem-n;
     }
    printf("remaining sticks=%d",n);
if(rem==1){
            printf("Player wins");
                break;
           }
else if(rem==0){
                 printf("Com wins");
                 break;
                }
else{
        if(rem>6){
                  if((rem-6)<=4){
                                 n=rem-6;
                                }
                  if((rem-6)>4){
                                n=4;
                                }
                      }
        if(rem==6) n=1;
        if(rem<6){
                        n=rem-1;
                 } 
        printf("Com chooses: %d",n);
       }
          printf("Remaining sticks=%d",rem);
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",n);` should be `scanf("%d", &n);`. And learn to indent your code. Its painful to read un-indented code.

Comment: Real programmers use indents :|

Comment: Enable all warnings - this error could have been caught by the compiler: `warning: format '%d' expects type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int'`

Comment: BTW `for(;1;)` Not necessary 1. E.G.`for(;;)`

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` function expects address of the variable, you have passed the (value of) variable itself.

`scanf("%d",n);`

Use this way:

`scanf("%d",&n);  // '&' is 'address of' operator and evaluates to address of the variable`

You are getting Seg Fault because `scanf` treats `n` as address of some variable, however `n` contains some garbage value, and may be that garbage value is some inaccessible/disallowed address in memory, therefore you get Seg Fault.

It is an undefined behavior, may be tomorrow you restart your system and do not get Seg Fault, but anyways your code will not work the way you want it to.

Comment: Thank u.The silly mistake I made after a long gap from programming.